# Defining a Class: Module takes at most 2 arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a basic game using Python3 and Pygame. I have managed to create a player character using the Pygame font render function. However, I would like to create the player as a object of an entity class (more as a practice than necessity but would be beneficial with scale I feel). However, it produces the error "module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given).

```py
import pygame

...

class Player(pygame.font):

    def __init__(self, Font, size):

        self.Font = Font
        self.size = size

player = Player(player, None, 36)
```

...

I was hoping this would enable me to create numerous player objects with varying attributes. I am very new and this does not work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `player = Player(None, 36)` See [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Comment: are you sure font=None?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys, my follow up is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbid76 already told you in a comment what's wrong with your code:

If you have an initializer like this

```
def __init__(self, Font, size):
```

you need to pass two arguments when creating an instance of the class:

```
player = Player(None, 36)
```

When you're working with an instance of a class and calling a method, the first parameter (usually called `self`) will always automatically be a refrence to the instance.

Also, when working with pygame, you should subclass the [`Sprite` class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) for your entities. Subclassing the `font`-module doesn't make much sense.

---

Here's a simple, runnable example:

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

TILESIZE = 32

def w2s(pos):
    x, y = pos
    return x*TILESIZE, y*TILESIZE

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, font, char, color, w_pos, layer, ai, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        # create an empty image
        self.image = pygame.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE), flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # we use a layer to the player is on top of the ground images
        self._layer = layer
        # here we store the position in the grid
        self.pos = w_pos
        # let's render the font
        s, r = font.render(char, color)
        # ensure it's centered and blit it onto 'image'
        r.center = self.rect.center
        self.image.blit(s, r.topleft)
        # now we can position our image
        # w2s translates the world position to the screen position
        # e.g. (0, 0) -> (0, 0), (1, 0) -> (32, 0) etc
        self.rect.topleft = w2s(w_pos)
        # a method that handles how this actor acts
        self.ai = ai

    def update(self, dt, events):
        # just call the ai method if there's one
        if self.ai:
            self.ai(self, dt, events)

# a method that looks for key presses and moves the actor on the grid
def player_handler(self, dt, events):
    for e in events:
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pygame.K_UP:    self.pos = self.pos[0], self.pos[1] - 1
            if e.key == pygame.K_DOWN:  self.pos = self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + 1
            if e.key == pygame.K_LEFT:  self.pos = self.pos[0] - 1, self.pos[1]
            if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: self.pos = self.pos[0] + 1, self.pos[1]
        self.rect.topleft = w2s(self.pos)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    clock, dt = pygame.time.Clock(), 0

    # a sprite group for all sprites
    sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()

    # some more groups, because why not? maybe came in handy later
    walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
    players = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle() 

    font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Consolas', 32)

    # create stuff
    x, y = 0, 0
    for line in ['           ',
                 ' ##########',
                 ' #........#',
                 ' #........#',
                 ' #....@...#',
                 ' #........#',
                 ' #........#',
                 ' ##########']:
        for char in line:
            if char == '@':
                Actor(font, '@', pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), (x, y), 1, player_handler, sprites, players)
                Actor(font, '.', pygame.Color('darkgrey'), (x, y), 0, None, sprites)
            elif char == '#':
                Actor(font, '#', pygame.Color('lightgrey'), (x, y), 0, None, sprites, walls)
            elif char == '.':
                Actor(font, '.', pygame.Color('darkgrey'), (x, y), 0, None, sprites)
            x += 1

        y += 1
        x = 0

    # pretty standard pygame game loop
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites.update(dt, events)
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed player as you suggested but the error remains the same. It points to the 'class Player(pygame.font)' as the offender. My thinking in using the font subclass as opoosed to sprite was because I'm making a game that only uses letters for it's graphics. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Yes, it is. First of all, `pygame.font` is not a class, but the whole font module. Also, even if you only use letters for graphics, you probably still want `Surface` objects to blit onto the screen, and a pygame `Sprite` is basically a `Surface` in combination with the position of where to draw it (via the `rect` attribute). Of course, in the end, it depends on what your game is all about: like, you do only want to display text to be read by the player or do your objects move around the screen?

Comment: In that case would the pygame.freetype.Font module be preferred as it outputs a Surface and a Rect? I'm creating a very basic roguelike and trying to learn as I go. I prefer the readability of pygame to libtcod but I'm very new so stumble often.

Comment: After looking through the pygame site again, there are quite a few tutorials on there. I will follow those to completion and probably try my idea again using the Sprite module as my character basis. Thanks for input.

Comment: @MartinJones Maybe it helps; I added a simple roguelike example to my anser.

Comment: That's very kind of you to take the time to produce this. I will definitely use this to aid my learning.